# How to rewrite the parameters in request body when using Apache

Tags: apache

When using Apache, we may make it work as a reverse proxy, change some value of the parameters, and redirects the request.

Suppose there's a GET method reaches, 
such as below:

```
curl  -i -k  -X GET "https://domain.com/getall.xml?aa=111&bb=222"
```

In order to change the value of aa or bb, we could use mod_rewrite to operates on %{QUERY_STRING}.

But if we put the parameters aa and bb in the request body, or using a POST method to submit  some of our requests, such as below:

```
curl  -i -k -X GET -d "aa=111&bb=222" https://domain.com/getall.xml
```

How could we change the value of aa or bb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as if the data is passed as `GET` or appended in the URL, `Apache mod_rewrite` should be able to change the value.

If the data is passed as `POST`, then `Apache` cannot use `mod_rewrite` to process & change the value, you will have to manipulate it inside your code.

Comment: Thanks, Rakesh. Seems it's a bad news for me.

Comment: @User807953 Sorry, I hope you could work that in your code and manipulate it. Also, work on the acceptance area :-) (Vote/Answer)

Comment: I'm not going to let the Web Service code to manipulate it. In fact, I'm considering to make some change on the module of mod_rewrite, or write another module. Hope that works.

Comment: Cool. Let us know. Post it somewhere or your personal github repository, I would like to see it.

Comment: That's OK, when I begin, I would let you know. Haha

Comment: I think we already have a similar project now, hehe. http://parp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Be aware, it could eat your server memory if the request body is large and there is high traffic to the site - it could bring down the server.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Rakesh! That what I worry about, maybe I need some dedicated machines to run may service.