# Redirect and change the request method and content

Tags: apache

I was reading the mod_rewrite documentation but haven't found an example to match the following scenario.

The use will try to use a GET request to /api/getCars.
On apache I need to change this request to POST method, to a different server, like https://internal_server/getAllCars, and I need to add some content on the body of this request and send it as x-www-form-urlencoded Content Type.

Which apache module do I have to use to achieve this behavior.
Can anybody provide any example?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably use programming language for such thing, not apache configuration...

Comment: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421808/how-to-rewrite-the-parameters-in-request-body-when-using-apache answers my question... it's not possible.